# struct has no member named

Tags: c, arrays, function, data-structures

My program contains a structure containing two array members. I've called the structure to a void function within function parameters.

structure definition:

```
struct caketime
{
    double baking_time [4]={20,75,40,30};
    double prepare_time[4]={30,40,25,60};
};
```

The void function:

```
void prepareorder(struct caketime p) {

int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
    {
        if(p.prepare_time[i]==25)
            printf("Choclate");
        else if (p.prepare_time[i]==30)
            printf("Sponge Cake");
        else if (p.prepare_time[i]==45)
            printf("Meringue");
        else if (p.baking_time[i]==60)
            printf("Red_velvet");
    }
}
```

When I compile this program, I get the errors described below:

```
In function 'prepareorder': error: 'struct caketime' has no member named 'prepare_time'
error: 'struct caketime' has no member named 'baking_time'
```

What seems to be the problem over here?

Comment: Are they declared in separate files? Show us definition and creation and assignment.

Comment: That struct definition isn't valid C.  If you're going to use initializers, you need an identifier after the struct definition and the initializers come after that.

Comment: Your structure "definition" should not compile.

Comment: Don't initialize the array in your `struct`.

Comment: Please show us a complete self-contained source file that exhibits the problem, along with the exact complete error messages you get from your compiler. And be sure you're compiling it as C, not as C++; your struct definition might actually compile if you're using a C++ compiler in C++11 mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try,

```
struct caketime
{
   double baking_time[4];
   double prepare_time[4];  
};
```

instead of,

```
struct caketime
{
   double baking_time [4]={20,75,40,30};
   double prepare_time[4]={30,40,25,60};
};
```

You should not initialize the array elements inside the structure.